# Updating a contact Entity does not show picklist text in CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dataverse

I am using the latest .NET 6 projects to add and update accounts and contacts.

```
microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client\1.0.9\

var contactUpdate = retrievedContact.Entities[0];

contactUpdate["address1_stateorprovince"] = "OR";
contactUpdate["address1_country"] = "USA"; 

serviceClient.Update(contactUpdate);
```

The `address1_stateorprovince` and `address1_country` are saved to the CRM sandbox and are able to be retrieved correctly, however, the picklist does not display the value OR (Oregon) or USA (United States) in the CRM backend?

How do I set the update so the picklist will display the value in the CRM backend

Comment: which picklist you are referring to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fields `address1_stateorprovince` & `address1_country` are both out of the box (defined my Microsoft) Text fields and not Picklist fields. They should be saved as Text and would be retrived as Text values in your case "OR" "USA"

Comment: Did it helped, or still facing issue?

Comment: I am updating contact records in the CRM sandbox. The  address1_stateorprovince and address1_country appear to be setup correctly in the sandbox since I can select from the option list OR and it displays correctly. When I update the controls using Update(contact) from my code the labels for these controls do not show in the sandbox backend. Yet I can query the contact and the values are returned correctly. 
I saw one other post that had the same issue I am having with no response.

Comment: Make sure you are updating and verifying in same table and field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked and believe the contact is correct. See code above.  I am a developer with limit exposure to CRM. The OptionSet seems to be attached to the sandbox fine since it allows me to select a state, but does not come through in my query in my code. Stumpted at the point.